# Why interaction attributes improve the performance of Linear Regression

Tags: statistics, weka, regression

I am working on Weka using Linear Regression Model. I realized that by multiplying two relevant attributes from my dataset and add this as an extra attribute i improve the performance of the Linear Regression.
However, i cannot understand why! Why my multiplying two relevant attributes have better results.

Answer (score 1):

This is a sign that the function you're approximating isn't linear in the original inputs, but it is in their product. In effect, you've reinvented multivariate [polynomial regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_regression).

E.g., suppose the function you're approximating has the form *y* = *a* × *x*² + *b* × *x* + *c*. A linear regression model fitted on *x* only won't give good results, but when you feed it both *x*² and *x*, it can learn the correct *a* and *b*.

The same is true in the multivariate setting: a function might not be linear in *x*<sub>1</sub> and *x*<sub>2</sub> separately, but it might be in *x*<sub>1</sub> × *x*<sub>2</sub>, which you call an "interaction attribute". (I know these as cross-product features or feature conjunctions; they're what the polynomial kernel in an SVM computes, and that's why SVMs are stronger learners than linear models.)